# Element wise average of arrays with different lengths from a dataframe

Tags: python, statistics, mean

First I will explain what I wish to occur.
I have a lot of arrays but say 3 as an example with different lengths. I want to get the average from comparing the arrays by each element.

```
A = [0,10,20]

B = [10,40,60,80]

C = [50,70]

Expected outcome = [20,40,40,80]
```

What I've tried is using zip_longest from itertools and using the mean function from statistics.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from statistics import mean

outcome = [mean(n) for n in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=0)]
```

However as specified the fill value is 0 and so the outcome is not the one desired. Because of using the mean function I cannot set the fillvalue to None. Would I have to use a different function to calculate the mean? Or another method to get an element wise average of different lengthen arrays.

Edit: Apologies but forgot to talk about the origins of the arrays. So the arrays are from a pandas dataframe where in each row of a column the value is an array of x length.

Edit2: Adding more meaningfull data

Create dataframe using pandas of a csv file

Select portion of dataframe with 2 conditions

Try to get element wise average from 3rd column that satisfies the 2 conditions

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

sec1 = df[(df['Color'] == 'blue') & (df['Type'] == 21)

outcome = [np.nanmean(n) for n in zip_longest(sec1['time'], fillvalue=float("nan"))]

print(outcome)
```

Where sec1['time'] has the output where the arrays are different lengths

```
2168    [0, 10, 20, 29, 44, 47, 59, 71, 94, 198...
2169    [0, 0, 7, 12, 47, 84, 144, 163, 222...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach, is to use `nan` as fillvalue and filter out (using [`filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)) the values when computing the mean, as below:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, filterfalse
from statistics import mean
from math import isnan

a = [0, 10, 20]
b = [10, 40, 60, 80]
c = [50, 70]

outcome = [mean(filterfalse(isnan, n)) for n in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=float("nan"))]
print(outcome)
```

**Output**

```
[20, 40, 40, 80]
```

I suggest you use [`fmean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean):

```
outcome = [fmean(filterfalse(isnan, n)) for n in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=float("nan"))]
print(outcome)
```

is faster than `mean`, from the documentation:

> This runs faster than the mean() function and it always returns a
> float. The data may be a sequence or iterable. If the input dataset is
> empty, raises a StatisticsError.

Another alternative is to use numpy [`nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import numpy as np

a = [0, 10, 20]
b = [10, 40, 60, 80]
c = [50, 70]

outcome = [np.nanmean(n) for n in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue=float("nan"))]
print(outcome)
```

**Output**

```
[20.0, 40.0, 40.0, 80.0]
```

Comment: With regards to the first solution using filterfalse I run into the error TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. Please check the edit in the question I added in.

Where the error is pointing towards  311     if iter(data) is data:
--> 312         data = list(data)
    313     n = len(data)
    314     if n < 1:

Comment: using fmean also runs into the same problem

Comment: And using np.nanmean results in TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type. Should've specified the origin of the arrays sorry.

Comment: Please add meaningful data

Comment: Have added all the code I have, should've done so at the start to make things clearer sorry